# Restricting Video upload to mp4 format alone - in media module

Tags: 7, media

I have been struggling put restriction for uploading video to upload only mp4 videos in media module, other media content like image etc. can be uploaded, but I need to put restriction for video type alone.

I am newbie in Drupal, can some one help me in this, what are the places I need to change in media module.

[image: While Adding File]

[image: Restrict video upload to mp4 only]

[image: don't want other video format, only mp4]

I would really appreciate any help on this. I did found `sites\all\modules\media\includes\media.pages.inc` file which had a function `media_add_upload_validate($form, &$form_state)` also then I found `sites\all\modules\media\includes\media.variables.inc` which had function `media_variable_default` and `media_variable_get`. Then I got lost. I am not sure if these are the correct files where I need to make the changes. Also I was wondering if I have to make change in Drupal core module to do the video upload restriction to mp4 perfectly.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for whoever has up-voted this question to encourage me :)

Comment: @Ajit Thanks for editing, really sorry for errors in asking question.

Comment: No need to apologize. We all make mistakes ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to admin/config/media/browser to change settings.

[image]

Comment: WOW :D ur awesome @Anil Sagar !!!! just one quick question will this modification be reflect in all the places or do i have to some other place as well, to make sure upload and error messages are changed correctly

Comment: What do you mean by all places ?

Comment: by all places i mean all the error messages which are displayed when i tried to upload other files like flv or mpeg??

Just wanted to make sure making change in this place is enough. Thank you so much for quick reply

Comment: Yes, It's taken care by the module... The error messages that you see are rendered from a template..

Comment: It is working great but it is taking time to show error, It is waiting for file to get uploaded and only after that it shows the error is there any way to show the error before file gets uploaded.